# Jquery .on for content added in the future

Tags: javascript, jquery, data-binding

I'm using "[infinite scroll plugin](http://www.infinite-scroll.com/infinite-scroll-jquery-plugin/)" to add content dinamically. 
In every post I have a Like button but it doesn't work for content added via "infinite scrolling"

[image]

HTML (erb)

```
<% current_user.likes?(post) ? like_icon_name = "icon-thumbs-up" : like_icon_name = "icon-thumbs-up-alt" %>

<%=link_to "", url_for(controller: "like", action:"toggle", resource_name: post.class.to_s, resource_id: post.id), class:"like #{like_icon_name}", remote: true%>
```

HTML (generated)

```
<a class="like icon-thumbs-up-alt" data-remote="true" href="/it/like/toggle?resource_id=1&amp;resource_name=Photo"></a>
```

**like.js**

```
$(document).on("ready page:load", function() {
      $("a[data-remote].like").on("ajax:success", function(e, data, status, xhr){
        if(xhr.responseText){
            $(e.target).toggleClass("icon-thumbs-up-alt icon-thumbs-up");
        }else{
            console.log(xhr);
        }

    });
});
```

**Scrolling.js**

```
// usage:
// $(elem).infinitescroll(options,[callback]);

// infinitescroll() is called on the element that surrounds 
// the items you will be loading more of

$(document).on('ready page:load',  function() {

    $('#posts').infinitescroll({

      navSelector  : "nav.pagination",            
                     // selector for the paged navigation (it will be hidden)

      nextSelector : "nav.pagination .next a:first",    
                     // selector for the NEXT link (to page 2)

      itemSelector : "#posts div.post",          
                     // selector for all items you'll retrieve

      debug        : false,                       
                     // enable debug messaging ( to console.log )

    }, function(arrayOfNewElems){

            $(document).trigger('scrolled');

             // optional callback when new content is successfully loaded in.

             // keyword `this` will refer to the new DOM content that was just added.
             // as of 1.5, `this` matches the element you called the plugin on (e.g. #content)
             //                   all the new elements that were found are passed in as an array

        });


});
```

page:load is for "[turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks/)"

Comment: Could you add the code about the click event of that Like Buton?

Comment: done. Question updated

Comment: Thx, try edit like.js with : `$(document).on("ajax:success", "a[data-remote].like", function(....`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was that your evant handler was (**directly-**) bound to an element **injected** into the page.

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on(). <sup>[source: [jquery doc](http://api.jquery.com/on/)]</sup>

You have to use delegated events to attach your event handler. Done here by providing a selector in the call to on(), bound to an element `that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached (e.g. the document element)`:

```
$(document).on("ajax:success", "a[data-remote].like", function(...){
    ...
});
```

Comment: I got my event called twice. Do you know how to prevent this?